# How to use antd with remix?

Tags: antd, remix.run

Is there a proper way of using ant with remix?

Using antd (ant.design) version 5. Tried adding the following to the root.tsx (as well as route files) file in remix project but styles still don't work:

```
import styles from "antd/dist/reset.css";

export function links() {
   return [
     {
       rel: "stylesheet",
       href: styles,
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, right now there is no easy way to use Ant Design without budled css file. As remix doesn't support bundling css yet, also there is no option to overridde esbuild config to add such plugin. But Remix team is working on such feature: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/1302#discussioncomment-1913510

**UPDATE**
Actually, there is a option to export whole ant design 5 styles into one css file, which you can include in your project. Check this part: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#whole-export

Answer (score 1):

I went with the [Whole export](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#whole-export) approach to generate the styles using a loader

```
// app/routes/antd[.]css.tsx
import { ConfigProvider, type ThemeConfig, theme } from "antd";
import { extractStyle } from "@ant-design/static-style-extract";
import { type LoaderArgs } from "@remix-run/server-runtime";
import { getThemeSession } from "~/utils/theme.server";

const themeLight = {
  token: {
    colorPrimary: "#4cb75b",
    colorPrimaryBg: "#dbf1db",
  },
  algorithm: [theme.defaultAlgorithm],
};

const themeDark: ThemeConfig = {
  token: {
    colorPrimary: "#55bf63",

    // generate using https://ant.design/theme-editor
    colorPrimaryBg: "#233327",
    colorLink: "#55bf63",
    colorLinkActive: "#3d994c",
    colorLinkHover: "#7ccc84",
  },
  algorithm: [theme.darkAlgorithm],
};

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const themeSession = await getThemeSession(request);
  const theme = themeSession.getTheme() || "light";

  const css = extractStyle((node) => (
    <ConfigProvider theme={theme === "dark" ? themeDark : themeLight}>
      {node}
    </ConfigProvider>
  ));

  return new Response(css, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/css",
    },
  });
};
```

Then you can add it in your links on the `root.tsx`

```
// app/root.tsx
export function links() {
  return [
     {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "/antd.css",
     },
  ];
}
```

When I get more time, I will look at how to implement the [export on demand](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#export-the-css-files-on-demand) I think it would work with an approach like emotion: https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/main/emotion/app/entry.server.tsx

Comment: The file name should be "antd[.]css.tsx".

Comment: You're correct, it's a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: adding `ConfigProvider` to the `extractStyle` is adding bunch of links to the document delaying the css load again. But without it, I couldn't set the themes. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

On version 5+, all you need to do is import the components and use. No need to import the css anymore, as mentioned [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5). You may add a ConfigProvider to app/root.tsx if you need to customize the theme.

```
import { Button, DatePicker } from 'antd';

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary">PRESS ME</Button>
      <DatePicker placeholder="select date" />
    </>
  );
}
```

The reset file should be added to app/root.tsx, only if you need to reset the basic styles.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work, the styling is still not applied.

Comment: This is false. You have to come up with a way to load the styles into the page yourself, otherwise the first page load will lack styles.

Comment: @quinn Have you found a working way to solve this?

Comment: @StalinGino unfortunately I haven't. I basically had to disable SSR in remix :(

Comment: I have moved to nextjs14 with app router which is supported by ant & nextjs app router is almost a copy of Remix. https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next

Comment: @StalinGino I was able to use their new static export plugin. it basically just exports all the styles as a stylesheet which you can then link. it includes all styles rather than only the components you use, but it works. https://ant.design/docs/blog/extract-ssr